# Spouse have French and Swedish nationality which residence permit non EU should apply?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, marriage, sweden, french-citizens

I am non EU, we did marriage in Sri Lanka. My wife having Swedish passport now working in France, so I applied my long stay Visa application as a spouse of European National, to live in France, they issued me short stay visa (3 months) and told you come and apply your residence permit in prefecture. Now I am in France. It is normal process but now we found out that she is also having valid French ID Card as she born in France but after she moved Sweden and lived there until recently, so we don't know that my application as a spouse of EU national will work or not.

On the other hand if I present my application as the spouse of a French national, there are two main difficulties, which are mentioned in embassy sites and other locations:

- Spouse of French national must have long stay visa (more than 3 months) to able to apply residence permit. (which I don't have)
- Marriage must be register in France. I don’t know how to register our marriage in France because I have only 2 weeks left in my short stay Visa.

Any idea would be great!

Comment: I'm afraid your understanding is correct.

Comment: I don't really see a precise question to answer here...

Answer (score 1):

Just converting Gala comment into an answer. Unfortunately, since your wife is a French citizen, the process is governed primarily by the laws of France and not the EU. You will have to go through that process instead, which involves a considerably different (and arguably more stringent) beauracracy.